# How to Raise DoesNotExist - Django SoftDelete?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, python-3.6, django-2.1

I have a Abstract Model  SoftDelete like follow.

```
class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)

class SoftDeleteModel(models.Model):
     is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=0)
     deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

     objects = SoftDeleteManager()

     def delete(self):
         self.is_deleted = True
         self.deleted_at = timezone.now()
         self.save()

     class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Employee(SafeDeleteModel):
   pass
```

Whenever model gets deleted i set `is_deleted` to `True` and updating the timestamp `deleted_at`, and created the custom manager to override initial queryset which return only non deleted fields(is_deleted=False).

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=1)
employee.delete()
employee.refresh_from_db() // not raising DoesNotExist
```

But lets say i have a `Employee` model which uses the `SafeDeleteModel` for soft delete, after deleting the model like `Employee.objects.get(pk=1).delete()` when i call `employee.refresh_from_db()`,its not raising `DoesNotExist`, but updates the value of is_deleted, deleted_at as expected, what mistake i made here, why its not raising `DoesNotExist`?

Comment: It will raise error only when you completely delete the object but here you are just populating a field is_deleted as true.so when you again going to delete it,it is able to find the object again and not raising the object does not exist.

Comment: @VIVEKVIKASH (https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-safedelete)[this] library also they are updating a field. called `deleted`, still it raises `DoesNotExist`

Comment: I copy&pasted your code and cannot reproduce your issue. `refresh_from_db()` raises DoesNotExist. (note: I wrote `abstract = True` not `abstarct = True`, assuming this is just a typo on SO, not in your code)

Comment: > test = Deletable.objects.create()
> test
<Deletable: Deletable object>
> test.is_deleted
0
> test.delete()
> test.refresh_from_db()
user.models.DoesNotExist: Deletable matching query does not exist.

Comment: @dirkgroten i tested in `shell`, still i am getting same issue. let me check one more time

Comment: Wait, according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model.refresh_from_db) `refresh_from_db` is using `_base_manager`, not `_default_manager`, in Django 1.11 it's using `_default_manager`. Seems this was changed from 2.0 to 2.1.

Comment: @dirkgroten so  your output are based on django-1.11?

Comment: yes, i don't see any release notes mentioning a change in `refresh_from_db` so i didn't think it would have changed. and I don't understand why it has changed.

Comment: from [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager](this) they mentioned like not to filter any results in base_manager, but in my case it make sense right?

Comment: @dirkgroten so i have to add custom manager as _base_manager right?

Comment: if you do that, it'll work yes. Meaning also that related lookups will filter out soft deleted objects correctly. I can see why refresh_from_db was changed, it make sense to use the base_manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been a [change in Django 2.1](https://github.com/django/django/commit/d065c92678f5d11a70b88e195c6357576eb3a2ef): `refresh_from_db()` now uses a model's `_base_manager`, not the `_default_manager` anymore, like for related queries. This to ensure an object can be refreshed even if it cannot be found by the default manager.

So you should set your `SoftDeleteManager` as the base manager using `base_manager_name`. But note this comment:

> Base managers aren’t used when querying on related models. For example, if the `Question` model from the tutorial had a `deleted` field and a base manager that filters out instances with `deleted=True`, a queryset like `Choice.objects.filter(question__name__startswith='What')` would include choices related to deleted questions.

Also I don't know how you would retrieve any object that has been deleted after you make this change, except if you make a special manager to *not* filter the deleted objects (e.g. `deleted_objects`).

Note also that I would expect the *safedelete* package you referred to in your comments to have the same issue, as it's not changing the `_base_manager` either.

Comment: `Base managers aren’t used when querying on related models.`, means it won't use any managers when querying related models? and from the docs `A manager that filters results in get_queryset() is not appropriate for use as a base manager.` so using my custom manager as `base_manager`  is bad practice?

Comment: It's a bit confusing. Assuming `Employee` has a `ForeignKey` to `Company`.  The base manager is used when you do this: `company.employees.all()` will be based on the base manager, but `Company.objects.filter(employees__name__icontains="charles")` will not. Because `objects` here is the `Company`'s manager and the query expression doesn't use the related manager.

Comment: The reason Django docs says it's not appropriate to filter out results in a base manager is that in the above case `company.employees.all()` will not give you the deleted objects, so you can't even do `company.employees.filter(is_deleted=True)`. So there's no way to get the filtered out objects even if you wanted to.

Comment: Also aggregations like `Company.objects.annotate(num=Count('employees'))` will contain your deleted instances, because they are direct database queries.

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable comments., i think though my custom manager filter deleted objects like `company.employees.all()` , still its a desired behaviour(since we are filtering deleted objects only)., so i think my using custom manager as base manager makes sense.

Comment: Yes, probably, just beware of the related queries, especially in the future, that might give unexpected results if you forget to filter on `is_deleted`.

Comment: Yes, I think in such scenario, splitting queries like `ques_pks = Question.objects.values("id").filter(name__startswith='what')` and `Choice.objects.filter(pk__in=set(ques_pks))` will make sense, but comes with cost of performance and multiple queries.